# SQL Create Table with Next sequence value Format : Incorrect syntax near 'for'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table with ID as next sequence with plus one number.
But i have a format to be defined for the same for the sequence number. When i tried the below SQL query i am getting error

> Incorrect syntax near 'for'

What are all the changes required for the SQL query.
Below are SQL queries:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE person_Sequence AS 
    INT START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE Person(

  ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
  Last_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  First_Name VARCHAR(30),
  Created_Date datetime NOT NULL,
  Updated_Date datetime NOT NULL,
  Payload VARBINARY(MAX) not null,

  CONSTRAINT pk_tbl_PERSON_ID DEFAULT 
  FORMAT((NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.person_Sequence),'PER000000#') for ID,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK  (ISJSON(Payload) > 0)

);
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler to use a autoincrement for the ID column _as INT_ data types, and just add `PER` to the ID in the presentation layer. You would probably end up with a more managable and quicker index as well

Comment: You could also make your 2 dates be automatically maintained by  using [see the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? _dbo.person_Sequence_ looks more like SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL 8.0 FAQ entry [Does MySQL 8.0 have Sequences?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-general.html#faq-mysql-have-sequences):

> No. However, MySQL has an `AUTO_INCREMENT` system

If [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) falls short for your needs, you'll have to build the whole sequence mechanism yourself.